# Every Interval of the form $[0,x)$ where $0<x<1$ is open?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am confused on how to show that:

In the metric subspace $S=[0,1]$ of Eucledian Space $R^1$, every interval of the form $[0,x)$ where $0<x<1$ is an open set in $S$ by using just definitions.

This question was posted already before but the answers attack for the proof is by using the theorem:

If $(S,d)$ is a metric subspace of $(M,d)$ and $X$ is a subset of $S$.Then $X$ is open in $S$ if and only if $X=A\cap S$ for some open set $A$ in $M$. Which is relatively easy than by using definition.

Could someone help me to prove the problem by using just definitions?

Here is my attempt: (Note:A  set $Y$ is open in $S$ if all its points are interior).

Let $Y=[0,x)$ and $S=[0,1]$. I must show that all the points in $Y$ are interior relative to $S$. This means that for all $y\in Y$ there is some open interval $B_s(y,r)$ that lies entirely in $Y$. A complication occurs by questioning what if $y=0$, I cant find an open interval $B_s(0,r)\subset Y$.

[UPDATE: Got it now, thanks everyone.]

Comment: The open balls in the (relative) topology of $S = [0,1]$ are sets of the form $B_S(y,r) = \{x \in [0,1] \mid |x - y| < r\} = B(y,r) \cap [0,1]$, where $B(y,r)$ is the usual ball $(y-r, y+r) \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks @Pedro M., I got it, but how can I show the existence of $B_s(0,r)\subset Y$

Comment: @Jr Antalan In order to talk about open sets, we have to define which sets are open. For subsets of topological spaces there is a natural way to do this, described by your "theorem". The ball you are looking for is $(y-\delta,y+\delta)\cap S$ such that $y+\delta<x$ (this delta exists because $y<x$).

Comment: Thanks again @uncountable. So it means that the ball I am looking for is the expression on your comment with intersection? that is $[0,1)$ for enough $\delta$? I am thinking that the ball/interval $B_s(0,r)$ that i am looking must be contained in $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without talking about subspace topologies, you can notice that $B_r(x)$ is in this case meant to be a subset of $[0,1]$. That is, *within the metric space* of $[0,1]$ with the (restriction of the) Euclidean metric, $B_r(x) = \{ y \in [0,1] : d(x,y) < r \}$ by definition. So for instance $B_{1/4}(0)=[0,1/4)$. So we can use this ball to, for example, prove that $[0,1/2)$ is open in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks @Ian, correct me if Im wrong, in particular I have $B_s(0,r)\subset S$ which is right, right?. My question now is, if my ball is $[0,1/4)$ clearly it is contained in $Y$, but is it open? I am thinking that the ball must be centered at $0$ with radius $r>0$, so it is $(-r,r)$ which is not contained in $Y$.

Comment: @JrAntalan $B_r(0)$ as a subset of the metric space $[0,1]$ is not $(-r,r)$, it is $[0,r)$. Note how I wrote $B_r(x) = \{ y \in [0,1] : \dots \}$, it is defined to be a subset of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Got it, a ball $B_s(y,r)$, $y\in Y$ are all $x's\in S$ satisfying $d(y,x)<r$. So if I have $B_s(0,1/4)=[0,1/4)$. thanks a lot. ^^, @Ian

Answer (score 2):

The "theorem" you use is actually the definition of the induced topology on a subset of a topological space. Now for the actual exercise, let $0<x<1$ be given. Now $(-x,x)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, hence $(-x,x)\cap S=[0,x)$ is open in $S$.

Comment: I got it @Uncountable thans, but how can I prove the problem without using the theorem, that is by using just definition?

Answer (score 1):

In the subspace topology, the open interval $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ corresponds to the interval $[0, \epsilon)$ in $[0,1]$. Thus the set $[0, \epsilon)$ is open in $[0,1]$ when considered a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: thanks.But I still dont get it, kindly help me. What should be my $B_s(0,r)$ that is contained in $Y$?